# I get a blank desktop with no icons , menu and bar

Tags: unity, menu, desktop-environments, taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn’t load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I setup the Ubuntu 12.10 for first time , when I login . desktop appear but there is no bar! there is no right click action there is nothing else!... only terminal is working with press: alt+ctrl+T !  The cursor moves but I see nothing else on the screen.

This is my first try with Ubuntu, any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks...

Comment: What graphics are you using? i.e. Nvidia, AMD. And have you tried installing proprietary drivers.

Comment: thanks @UriHerrera, I just can't find out the correct links for duplication most of the time. :( . How do you manage it.

Comment: @Web-E Use keywords.

Comment: How did you install it?